# Firebase user can not be logged out - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

1. I run the app in Xcode simulator and log in with user and password then I log out, the `logOutOutlet` and `bookingsOutlet` are hidden and `logInOutlet` button shows. So far it behaves as expected.

   - 2

Next, stop the app from Xcode and run it again, but now it behaves as if I was already logged in: shows `logOutOutlet`,bookingsOutlet, hides logInOutlet. It behaves in the same when the app is suspended, terminated or deleted. ( i.e, Stop in Xcode or cmd + H * 2 and swipe up.)
Now, assuming that I have an active logIn session in the next ViewController I try to retrieve data from FireBase Realtime DataBase, but I get this error. `Error Domain=com.firebase Code=1 "Permission Denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Permission Denied}. Why can I not log out completely?`

```
@IBAction func logOut(sender: AnyObject) {
    // if the current user is logged in, try to log out and if logout is successful:
    // hide: logOut button & bookings button
    // show: logIn button
  if FIRAuth.auth() != nil {

        do {
            try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()

            print("the user is logged out")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
             print("the current user id is \(FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)")
        }

        self.logInOutlet.hidden = false
        self.logOutOutlet.hidden = true
        self.bookingsOutlet.hidden = true
    } // end of if.. FIRAuth.auth()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // if the user is logged out
    // hide: logOut button & bookings button
    // show: logIn button
     // if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid == nil {
    if FIRAuth.auth() == nil {

        self.logInOutlet.hidden = false
        self.logOutOutlet.hidden = true
        self.bookingsOutlet.hidden = true

// it still prints the user id, why?
 if let userNOTLogged = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
            print("User should NOT be logged \(userNOTLogged)")

        }



        // if the user is logged in
        // hide: logIn Button
        // show: logOut button & bookings button
    } else if

   FIRAuth.auth() != nil {
        self.logInOutlet.hidden = true
        self.logOutOutlet.hidden = false
        self.bookingsOutlet.hidden = false
    }
}



   // Log in code


    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email.text!, password: password.text!, completion: { (authData, error) in

        let customError = error?.localizedDescription
        if error != nil {
            print(customError)

            // display an alert with the error
            self.displayAlert()

        } else {
            print("The user has been logged in")


    //if signIn was successful, instantiate the view controller with identifier SWrevelViewidentifier
         let toMenuOptions = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SWrevelViewidentifier")
            self.presentViewController(toMenuOptions!, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    })
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact same problem. Since this happens when you relaunch, try putting this code in your app.delegate.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.addAuthStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
  if let user = user {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party login? If so, you might have to use the corresponding command, like GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()

Comment: The reason why my code was not working was because .auth() is an object returned by FIRAuth and it may or may not contain a user. In order get the value for currentUser I should check for FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser  and in this case the value returned could be nil or the user that is logged in . As you suggested `addAuthStateDidChangeListener` works too.